# Unable to receive an email using AWS SES service in Laravel 9

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ses, laravel-9

I am completely new to AWS service. I am trying to receive an email using AWS SES service , add the emails those are being received into the S3 bucket, then fetching the objects of the bucket and adding them into database table.

I have tried in the following way:

```
public function receiveEmailSES(Request $request) {

        $file_name = $request->input('fileName');

        $client = new S3Client([
            'version' => 'latest',
            'region' => 'us-east-1',
            'credentials' => array(
                'key' => 'somekey',
                'secret' => 'somesecretkey',
            ),
        ]);

        
        $object = $client->GetObject(['Bucket' => 'task-email-receive-bucket', 'Key' => $file_name]);
        $body = $object['Body']->getContents();

    }
```

I am not able to understand how to add the email received in the S3 bucket.

I have fetched the s3object using the GetIObject method.

But then I will need to parse that email content and add the to, from , subject and body in a database table.

Kindly suggest what can be done.

Answer (score 0):

The file you get from S3 bucket is a simple email file in a standard format.

Fortunately, PHP has support to email messages by the `Mailparse` module, which can be installed as a PECL extension. https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mailparse.php
Initially take a look on the method `mailparse_msg_parse_file` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mailparse-msg-parse-file.php

Comment: After receiving the email content I need to insert in the S3 bucket. Here I have not inserted the email in the bucket, then how will it be possible to fetch the object from s3 bucket? And    is there any steps regarding how to use the MailParse extension? As there is no example in the php manual

Comment: You need to download the S3 file first. The library has no support for S3. Regarding examples - I don't know any. Try to follow docs of function, instead of examples to copy&paste.